# Why does "range(10) is range(10)" not return True?

Tags: python, python-3.x, range

As range objects can be used as dictionary keys, meaning they are immutable, why when doing `range(10) is range(10)`, it doesn't return `True`?

Comment: @Tomerikoo Be careful about testing that way -- doing that actually *does* print the same ID every time. The temporary `range` objects are garbage collected and the IDs get reused.

Comment: @bryan60 It seems to be more robust than that. I can define `d = {range(10):5}` and then later on assign `x = range(10)` and have `d[x]` work as expected. Ranges as keys wouldn't be useful without that behavior.

Comment: @bryan60 That's also incorrect. `range` overrides equality and hash functions so they're safe to use as keys.

Comment: Why do you think `range(10) is range(10)` **should be true** just because `range` objects are immutable? That doesn't follow at all.

Comment: @JohnKugelman you are right! I didn't know the garbage collector is "that fast"... was going to delete my initial comment, but will leave it for constructive discussion

Comment: @Tomerikoo note, CPython uses *reference counting* as its primary automatic memory management system. As an implementation detail, objects are reclaimed *immediately* as soon as their reference count reaches 0.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga so in that case when using `print(range(10))` in a way the counter goes back to 0 immediately after the line executes? Good to know, thanks! BTW, so save my dignity, I did run said line 2 times in a row **in a console** and got different IDs. But I believe this has something to do with code executed in console having its own memory space per line or something like that

Comment: @Tomerikoo yes, exactly. This is why `print(id(range(10)) == id(range(1)))` might be decieving, because in the expression `id(range(10)) == id(range(10))`, the range objects only exist long enough for the `id` function to be called! But you'll see something different if you do `x, y = range(10), range(10); print(id(x) == id(y))`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga wow I would guess it works on a line resolution (if that's a thing) but it even gets freed in between evaluations of the same line. interesting, I don't know if it's a typo when you wrote `range(1)` but actually it even works to support your example :D

Comment: @Tomerikoo yes, both illustrate the point :), probably the typo version even better! But yes, things don't work on a line by line basis. You can dissasemble into bytecode to get a better idea of what's going on, `import dis; print(dis.dis('id(range(10)) == id(range(1))'))`

Comment: Thanks @juanpa I like the fact that I learn new stuff just from conversation in comments and not even from asking a question. That's why I keep coming :)